# Trying to refresh bindings on Page, using ko.applyBindings ... error recieved

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am receiving the following error when I try to "refresh" my page and ko.applyBindings for the refresh. Here is the error:

You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:2102

and here is the code that performs the ko.applyBindings

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#modal-location .modal-form button").click(function () {
            var zip = document.getElementById("searchArg").value;
            alert(zip);

            ko.applyBindings(new theatreSel.TheatreModel(zip));
        });




    });
```

Note, I tried the ko.cleanNode() but it did not work, but maybe I didn't use it correctly. 
my binding is on the UL class = "results modal-scroll" ... is that where I should use the ko.cleanNode? If so, that did not work.

Comment: I saw a ticket earlier today that say ko.cleanNode does not work. The blog knockmeout.com had a post about it but you should not need to apply the bindings again. You should make a reset function that will override all your data with the new data. Or you can use an older version of ko that allows you to do this but causes sideeffects. Essentially everything will have multiple listeners for the same thing. So if you have a bool to show/hide something on click and you click it, the two bound elements will get called and essentially cancel each other out.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am fine with not having to apply bindings again, but it doesn't seem like even when you change the array that ko will display the new data, I tried to NOT apply the bindings and it doesn't change anything. this is very frustrating. but, thank you for your help. Regards

Comment: So it has to be bound once and then everything that is a knockout observable should get updated with the new reset value. Its possible your new theatreSel.TheatreModel(zip) is not making the view model correctly. I usually have the apply inside my view model but I can see why you would want it outside.